# Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
```

Can I ignore the title error? I have a component that once triggered runs 200 simulations, each time updating a count of the sims and assigning the winner to a keyed array.

However I presume because setCount is called in the useEffect that also checks the value, its reaching a depth.

```js
export default function Battle({ items, max = 200, }) {
  const bout = useBout()
  const brands = useSelector(state => groupBy(state.brands, "id"))
  const [ started, setStarted, ] = useState(true)
  const [ count, setCount, ] = useState(0)
  const [ simulations, setSimulations, ] = useState({})

  const teams = groupBy(bout.items, "teamId")
  const segments = useMemo(() => {
    return generateSegments({ teams, brands, simulations, count })
  }, [teams, brands, simulations, count ])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (items) {
      bout.load(items)
    }
  }, [ items, ])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (started && count <= max) {
      bout.simulate()
      const id = bout.items.find(item => item.winner)?.teamId

      setCount(count + 1)
      setWinner(id)
    }
  }, [ count, max, started, ])

  const onStart = () => {
    track("BATTLE_CLICK")
    setCount(0)
    setSimulations([])
    setStarted(true)
  }

  const setWinner = (id) => {
    const value = simulations[id] ? Number(simulations[id]) + 1 : 1

    setSimulations({ ...simulations, [id]: value, })
  }

  return <Segments segments={segments} onItemClick={onStart} />
}
```

Comment: can't you avoid this 200 simulations, since it will be performance lag

Comment: That does not fulfil the requirements set. The performance lag is a non issue for users who are expecting to run simulations. 200 is quite small compared to other parts of the project.